# Is the order of items in a hash_map/unordered_map stable?

Tags: c++, stl, hashmap, unordered-map

Is it guaranteed that when a hash_map/unordered_map is loaded with the same items, they will have the same order when iterated? Basically I have a hashmap which I load from a file, and from which I periodically feed a limited number of items to a routine, after which I free the hashmap. After the items are consumed, I re-load the same file to the hashmap and want to get the next batch of items after the point where I stopped the previous time. The point at which I stop would be identified by the key.

Comment: Not that I know of, although it's probable (unless your key is based on a pointer value) because no implementation I know of use randomness.

Comment: I use std::string as key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically no, they are not guaranteed to be in any particular order.

In practice however, given that you use deterministic hash function, what you want to do should be fine.

consider

```
std::string name;
std::string value;

std::unordered_map <std::string, std::string> map1;
std::unordered_map <std::string, std::string> map2;

while (read_pair (name, value))
{
    map1[name] = value;
    map2[name] = value;
}
```

you can reasonably expect that name-value pairs in `map1` and `map2` go in the same order.

Comment: Yes, that is my point - I am not interested in the order itself, but if it will be the same the next time I load the hashmap. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Apart from it being a bad idea in general to rely on behaviour that is not guaranteed, I think it's important to note that this relies on the fact that the *insertion order* is the same in both maps, which will not necessarily be preserved when reloading the files (since the iteration order will likely not match the original insertion order).

Comment: @John Bartholomew: I didn't understand the point about the insertion order - I insert the items as I parse the file, so is always the same.

Comment: @AlexanderVassilev: John is probably thinking of the very first time you insert the items, before the map is ever saved to disk. The order on disk won't match the order they were inserted that first time, even if everything is deterministic. I would say the full description of your question makes clear you don't care about that very first time, but the "headline question" doesn't exclude it, and neither does your first sentence: "when a hash_map/unordered_map is loaded with the same items" rather than "the same items in the same order".

Comment: Well, I don't save the map on disk. I only load it, the file is not generated from the map.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot safely do this. Firstly, it's not guaranteed by the standard, but even if you ignore the standard and look at real implementations, it is a bad idea.

Most hash table structures are not *history independent*. That is: the state of the hash table depends not only on what items it contains, but also what *order* they were inserted.

Here is a concrete example:

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

static const char* const NAMES[] = {
    "joe",
    "bob",
    "alexander",
    "warren",
    "paul",
    "michael",
    "george",
    "david",
    "peter"
};
static const int NAME_COUNT = sizeof(NAMES)/sizeof(NAMES[0]);

static void print_umap(const std::unordered_map<std::string, int>& m) {
    for (const auto& item : m) {
        std::cout << "  " << item.first << "\n";
    }
}

int main(void) {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> a;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> b;
    std::unordered_map<std::string, int> c;

    for (int i = 0; i < NAME_COUNT; ++i) {
        a[NAMES[i]] = 0;
        b[NAMES[NAME_COUNT - 1 - i]] = 0;
    }

    for (const auto& item : a) {
        c[item.first] = 0;
    }

    std::cout << "a:\n";
    print_umap(a);
    std::cout << "\n\nb:\n";
    print_umap(b);
    std::cout << "\n\nc:\n";
    print_umap(c);
    return 0;
}
```

When I build this using [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) and the [libc++](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) implementation of the C++ standard library, I get the following output:

```
a:
  peter
  george
  michael
  david
  paul
  bob
  warren
  alexander
  joe


b:
  joe
  alexander
  bob
  warren
  david
  paul
  michael
  george
  peter


c:
  joe
  alexander
  warren
  bob
  paul
  david
  michael
  george
  peter
```

Note that the order is different in every case. This is not at all unusual for hash tables.

Comment: I agree with this, but in my case the insertion order is guaranteed to be the same every time.

Comment: +1 @john. In my case the unordered map is populated during static initialization - and the order is not guaranteed.