# Why the output shows file 2 first?

Tags: c++, c++11, unordered-map, std

[image: My Data structure]

*Context*: I need this data structure to find the keywords of a particular file at a node. So the map is having file name and vector to store the keywords of that file.This is basically a small code i am using in mpi to find relationship between files at different nodes in  a parallel fashion.

Comment: I may be missing something very trivial but bear with me as i am only a beginner in C++.

Comment: Please paste your code as text.

Comment: For a start copy paste the code here, don't post an image.

Comment: I don't see why you are surprised. `unordered_map`s are unordered, they can come out in any order

Comment: @zch   sorry i tried posting this in text but there was a formatting problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of the elements of an `std::unordered_map` is ***not*** stable, which explains your output.

Read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13622590/2411320) for more and how to read the elements. Also next time search before asking a question and of course (almost) never post images of code, but use code tags.

From the [ref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map):

> Internally, the elements are not sorted in any particular order, but organized into buckets.

Comment: thanks, i thought that it is unlike map in a way that it keeps the insertion order...

Comment: You are welcome @Coffee_lover. It's not something trivial, that's why I upvoted your question. However, you didn't do the same for my answer...It's not good enough? I mean you saw something bad about it? Maybe my edit will improve the answer! :)

Comment: i am sorry, was caught up in the mpi work that i almost forgot but i did accepted it as answer.