# map a million strings to ints in c++11

Tags: string, c++11, dictionary, svm, sparse-matrix

I have a million ASCII strings, without duplicates, each at most 7 bytes long.  I need to map each string to a positive integer.  The largest of these ints should be *not much more than a million.*  Although initialization may be slow, lookup should be fast: given a string, return the corresponding int (or -1, if not found).  How can one implement this in C++11?

One solution: accumulate the strings into a `std::unordered_map<string,int>`; then iterate over the map, assigning the ints from an incrementing counter.  Then to lookup, just `unordered_map::find("foo")->second`.  But it smells like some other container would be faster and have less overhead (indices built in, rather than hand-coded).  Maybe `unordered_set` and pointer arithmetic??

The range restriction seems to make a perfect hash difficult.

(The int's range is restricted, because it indexes into a feature vector passed to [svm_light](http://svmlight.joachims.org/).  That software doesn't use sparse storage, so vectors with trillions of (mostly zero) elements make it run out of memory. So this string-to-int preprocessing sort of implements a sparse data structure.)

Comment: can you give an example for such mapping?

Comment: What am I missing ?  `10^6` strings, each no more than 7 bytes, and no duplicates ?

Comment: It's not a solution, but I would put them in a vector, sort it and just use a binary search.

Comment: Mark, O(n) lookup is way too slow.  Fran, O(log n) is better, but still slower than the O(1) of `unordered_map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe looks like [perfect hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function).

There are C++ libraries which implement perfect hash, for example [Tiny perfect hash library for C, C++, and Lua](https://github.com/wahern/phf).

Comment: Yes, in that terminology I need a nearly "minimal perfect hash function." But making one is [difficult](https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/manual/gperf.html).

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune did you look at the CHD base lib - link I provided? GNU gperf is quite outdated

Comment: Wow, an 80% load factor is great!  I'm mostly trying to avoid under 0.01% :)

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune yep, that's the point. I would be interested in the results of your tests

Comment: a 7 bytes sting fits into a int64_t, and the hash is ... itself!

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia Mmm... What about `The largest of these ints should be not much more than a million` ?

Answer (score 1):

Convert your strings to `int64_t`, store them in an `unordered_set`, and use the iterators as unique indexes.
Effectively you'll achieve O(1) lookup, plus O(N) for calculating the iterator offset. You'll also have a guarantee that the maximum index won't exceed the size of array.

```
  unordered_set<int> s;
  s.insert(10);
  s.insert(2000000);
  s.insert(5000000);

  int index = std::distance(s.find(10), s.end());
  cout << index << endl;
  index = std::distance(s.find(2000000), s.end());
  cout << index << endl;
  index = std::distance(s.find(5000000), s.end());
  cout << index << endl;
```

outputs:

```
1
2
3
```

Now that you have a unique mapping, use `unordered_map` to achieve your goal, and discard the `unordered_set`:

```
  unordered_set<int> s;
  unordered_map<int,int> m;
  s.insert(10);
  s.insert(2000000);
  s.insert(5000000);

  int index = std::distance(s.find(10), s.end());
  m[10] = index;
  cout << index << endl;
  index = std::distance(s.find(2000000), s.end());
  m[2000000] = index;
  cout << index << endl;
  index = std::distance(s.find(5000000), s.end());
  m[5000000] = index;
  cout << index << endl;

  s.clear();
  cout << m[10] << " " << m[2000000] << " " << m[5000000] <<  endl;
```

Lookups will be O(1).

Answer (score 0):

If you have exactly million of strings, each exactly 7 bytes long, then it's perfect prerequisite for using radix-sort; so basically first you store all 10^6 strings in in big array (it's only 7MB/6.7MiB, so quite manageable), then sort using radix-sort algorithm - time complexity *O(wn)*, *w* = 7, *n* = 10^6 in your case, can be implemented *in situ*. Details of implementation will matter to keep low constant on that linear complexity but radix sort is rather easy to implement.

As alternative to radix sort, you can simply treat strings as `uint64_t` and use `std::sort` (it implements well optimized intra-sort, which may perform as well as radix for your constraints, despite higher time complexity).

Once array is sorted, you iterate over it and put index of array into ordinary `std::unordered_map` with string as key. So in the end you created your perfect hashing in basically linear time and end up with reverse lookup in average *O(1)*.

[edit] For putting strings into unordered_map, you might want to implement your own hashing algorithm, I suggest using *djb2*, it has good statistical properties and is easy to implement.

Comment: Some strings are shorter than 7 bytes.  Even so, considering them as 64-bit ints is clever!

Comment: If the data structure used during looking is an `unordered_map`, why bother with sorting beforehand?  This doesn't sound simpler than my originally proposed solution.

Comment: Second sentence in your question was: "The largest of these ints should be not much more than a million" ;)

Comment: ok, I'll elaborate - your original suggestion was fine, but you're right - it might be too much overhead. I think, that implementing sort for continuous area of memory will work faster than jumping all over the place during iteration over `std::unordered_set`. So building your mapping will be *slightly* faster, then what you originally suggested.

Comment: I still don't see how sorting before filling the u_map helps.  The u_map stores the data [unpredictably](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13623172/2097284) so, whoosh, bye bye to locality of reference.

Comment: Hmm, you're right - it doesn't; I was too obsessed with generating ids, but if you have strings in some kind of container, then you can enumerate them already. Btw `std::string` of such small size enables SSO, so treating them as `uint64_t` for purpose of mapping results in very modest improvement.

Comment: On the other hand, if you have ids in sorted array, then you can implement binary-search-like algorithm, but instead splitting into 2, you can precalculate positions to jump into based on first few chars and do binary search on rest; for such small strings it might be faster than calculating hash. I'll try to implement this tomorrow, I wonder how it compares to simple umap solution.

Comment: See dau_sama's recently proposed solution before implementing binary search.